# Why the compiled results of package {oands} is null?

Tags: fonts, packages

Just now I try to use the fonts package "oands" to creat myself package, the procedure of compilation is successful, but the pdf outcome is null except the result corresponding the type of \textoands{z} with a wrong outcome in pdf. I wonder why.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong outcome"? Can you clarify your question please? Also, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: That means there is nothing to outcome but the one of \textoands{z}.

Comment: Then it is correct. The manual of the `oands` package says that `The OandS font currently consists of just two characters`, and that `The complete font may be printed by \textoands{\`z}`. So what you are seeing is all that there is to see.

Comment: Thanks,  so this is just a font package with only two character!

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual of the `oands` package, the font consists of only two characters, which can be printed using `` \textoands{` z} ``:

> The OandS font currently consists of just two characters.
>
> The complete font may be printed by \textoands{‘ z}.

We can make a test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{oands}

\begin{document}

1. \textoands{` z}

2. \textoands{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

3. \textoands{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\end{document}
```

And the printed result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank your anwser very much, I missed the top description of this package, and I never image there is such a fonts package with only two characters.

Comment: No worries. I must confess I don't see the point in a two character font. I read it twice to make sure I wasn't missing anything :)